# Wordpress plugin/theme or other wayout to create portable pages?

Tags: plugins, pages, plugin-recommendation, export

Here is my problem - I have my production server running my wordpress site. I have mirrored the site on my localhost to play around and make updates before I push them to production. Staging process is difficult since I have to backup databases and what not! I am trying to find a simple solution - if I add a new page to local server, test it and want to move it to the production, what's the best way to do it? I use Elementor page builder and does not give me an option to export a page and import it somewhere else. I basically want to create pages locally and maybe copy the code somehow and add it to production site without touching anything else (like database). Suggestions?

Comment: When you say you create a new page, are you creating a new template file or are you using your WP admin to create a new page there?

Comment: have you looked at the default wordpress import / export (look under tools).  I'm pretty sure it will solve your needs. If that doesn't work, and you don't want to move the database, You'd probably have to write your own import / export plugin for this.  You could export from wp_posts and wp_postsmeta based on a page_id, and then import the post, get a new page_id and insert your metadata.   That assumes there are no other tables being changed by your Elementor plugin.